# d3 label on stack bar which has enough space to show it

Tags: d3.js, label, stacked-chart

Im building a stack bar similar to  https://d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/barplot_stacked_percent.html. Im trying to add labels on each stack but want to show only in the stacks that has enough space to show it.
Below is the bar code

```
// Show the bars
svg.append("g")
.selectAll("g")
// Enter in the stack data = loop key per key = group per group
.data(stackedData)
.enter().append("g")
.attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.key); })
.selectAll("rect")
// enter a second time = loop subgroup per subgroup to add all rectangles
.data(function(d) { return d; })
.enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.group); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
    .attr("width",x.bandwidth())
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it. For those with similar issue, here is the code.

[image]

```
// code for displaying text

checkForText(d, y) {
if (y(d[0]) - y(d[1]) >= 10) {
  return (d[1] - d[0]).toFixed(2);
}
}  

//stacked bar code

var bars =  g
  .selectAll("mybar")
  .data(stackedData)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "bar-group")
  .attr("fill", function (d) { return color(d.key); });

  bars.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function (d) { return d; })
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.data.group); })
  .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d[1]); })
  .attr("height", function (d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
  .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
  .append("svg:title")
  .text(function (d) {
    const key = Object.keys(d.data).find(key => d.data[key] === (d[1] - d[0]).toFixed(2));
    return `${(d[1] - d[0]).toFixed(2)}`
  })



bars.selectAll("text")
  .data(function (d) { return d; })
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.data.group); })
    .attr("y", (d) => {
    const pos = y(d[0]) - ((y(d[0]) - y(d[1])) / 2);
    return pos + 5;
  })
  .attr("height", function (d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
  .style("fill", "white")
  .style("font-size", "12px")
  .style("font-family", "mulish_medium")
  .text(d => self.checkForText(d, y))
```